# ajax return error on browser but success on dreamweaver

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, dreamweaver

I am writing a phone application with dreamweaver 6. 
My ajax returns error without any result on my browsers, and all my phone it doesn't return anything(which means the phone isn't reading the code), however it returned the desire result on dreamweaver live view.
below are the codes

```
//I removed the last part of the $uri for security reasons
var $uri="http://62.173.32.43?";

var Y1="87FBA0AC7252EDD6";


var Y2=Encrypt(key,uniqueSession);

var Y3=(Encrypt(key,MSISDN));
var fulladd = $uri + 
              "OPERATION=" +
              Y1.toString() + 
              "&SESSION_ID=" + 
              Y2.toString() + 
              "&MSISDN=" + 
              Y3.toString() + 
              "&USE_XML=True";


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: fulladd,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(){
        alert("done...");
    },
    complete: parseXML,
    error: function(){
        alert("Error Connecting, ensure you are connected to the internet");
    });
```

Comment: Instead of a generic error, print out the response that is returned. E.g., `error: function (response) { console.log(response); }`

Comment: is `$uri` different from the location of this page?

Comment: for the error log use `error: function (jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) { }` try logging all 3, and use `console.log()`

Comment: From what I've learned, Never use/trust WYSIWYG views/editors.

Comment: The error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://62.173.32.43.....aspx?OPERATION=87FBA0AC7252EDD6&SESSION_ID=35348D1FE01356585A8B7E6195A30C9BD55E7E675EE076D9752E32B5DA095EEA&MSISDN=bc143eb6c63a7a22c14abad86aa3e4fc&USE_XML=True. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Comment: You are making a cross-domain request which is not allowed unless CORS is enabled, and even then CORS isn't supported in all browsers. I suggest looking into the JSONP datatype (not to be confused with JSON)

Comment: Thanks @KevinB . Am on it now. Would I be able to retrieve xml data too? and will it work for mobile phones?

Comment: No, JSONP is a dataType in the same way XML is a dataType. they are two different ways of representing data. You could technically place xml into jsonp, however it doesn't really make sense to do so.

Comment: @KevinB, the data i need to receive is in xml format. I don't have control over the server side program. My work was to receive the xml sent from the server.
Please, is there a way i can do this task?

Comment: Yes, place a server-side script on the same uri as the page that gets the xml for you, then request from that server-side script.

Comment: @KevinB, Thanks a lot. We'll go check for tutorials on jsonp.